# Leaflet - undefined value empty string

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm using Utgrid to display information about bicycle routes. Often there is no information, length or description is an empty field. As you can see the end result is "Opis szlaku: undefined". How can I get rid of this "undefined"? I would like to achieve an empty field instead.

```
var info = L.control();
info.options.position = 'bottomright';
info.onAdd = function (map) {
    this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info'); // create a div with a class "info"
    this.update();
    return this._div;
};

info.update = function (props) {
    this._div.innerHTML = (props 
        ? '<img src="img/' + props.data.route +'_'+ props.data.osmc_color +'_'+ props.data.osmc_background +'_'+ props.data.osmc_foreground + '.png" ><br /> ' + "<b>" + props.data.name + "</b><br />" + 'Długość: ' + props.data.distance + "<br />" + 'Opis szlaku: ' + props.data.description   
        : '');
};
```

props.data.distance - this should be replaced with an empty string or maybe space when the value is udefined. I'm searching for hours but can't find the right way.
Thanks!

Here's the working website (You need to hoover over coloured trails).

http://wojtas82.zrujnowane.pl/utf2.html#16/54.4897/18.4893/osm-rowerowe-piesze

Comment: `props.data.description || ''` or `(props.data.description) ? props.data.description : ''`

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I want to display the value when it is actually there. Only replace it with empty field when the value is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work, maybe the bracers have to be around the ternary as well.

```
info.update = function ( props ) {
    var str;
    if (props) {
        str = ' img route: ' + props.data.route +'_'+ props.data.osmc_color +'_'+ props.data.osmc_background +'_'+ props.data.osmc_foreground + '<br /> ' + '<b>' + props.data.name + "</b><br />" + 'distance: ' + props.data.distance + '<br />' + 'description: ' + (props.data.description ? props.data.description : '');
        this._div.innerHTML = str;
    }
};
info.update({
    'data' : {
        'route' : 'someRoute',
        'osmc_color' : 'blue',
        'osmc_background' : 'bg',
        'osmc_foreground' : 'fg',
        'name' : 'dataName',
        'distance' : '9000',
        'description' : undefined
    }
});
```

Comment: That works! I modified it a little:   info.update = function (props) {
   this._div.innerHTML = (props ?
   '<img src="img/' + props.data.route +'_'+ props.data.osmc_color +'_'+ props.data.osmc_background +'_'+ props.data.osmc_foreground + '.png" ><br /> ' + "<b>" + props.data.name + "</b><br />" + 'Długość: ' + (props.data.distance ? props.data.distance : '')  + "<br />" + 'Opis szlaku: ' + (props.data.description ? props.data.description : '')   : '');
  }; and now it works like it should. Thanks a lot!